# Why I am getting Geocoding API authentication error even after enabling Geocoding API?

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, geocoding

I enabled "Geocoding API"  for my Google Cloud platform project. Still it gives me an error:

*"Geocoding Service: This API project is not authorized to use this API.  For more information on authentication and Google Maps JavaScript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
_.xd @ js?libraries=geometry&key=[my_api_key]:79"*

Billing is already enabled on my account, I have a valid Api key and all other APIs like 'Directions service', Google maps javascript api, are all working fine. Only the geocoding api is giving error. I have also included sample code that I am trying to use. Can somebody help me to understand what I am doing wrong or is something missing?

```js
function GetLocation() {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var address = document.getElementById("txtAddress").value;
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    alert("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
                } else {
                    alert("Request failed.")
                }
            });
        };
```

Comment: My guess is that the Geocoding API is not enabled (even though you think it is).

Comment: The Geocode API shows up in my enabled API list on the dashboard.

Comment: If you follow the guides correctly and it doesn't work, I can only suggest that you try again, maybe try to generate a new API key, try to create a new project or contact Google Support. We are not Google support. Did you really enable the *Geocoding API*, not the *Geolocation API* which are 2 different things?

Comment: Thank you  MrUpsidown.  I have enabled both: Geocoding API, and the Geolocation API.

Comment: Are you still having this issue @Amruta?

Comment: @evan, I am still having this issue and I am following up with the Google Support team over this. Thanks to MrUpsidown for suggesting that. According to support team, there is some issue with the linking of my billable account to my current google project, hence I am getting those errors. Expecting to fix these issues soon.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for your update! Google's Tech team will help you out for sure. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: This issue resolved by Unlinking project from an existing Cloud Billing Account and linking it to an active billing account again. Google support team helped through the process.